# Beginner Swift: Converting string if letter in dictionary

Tags: swift, string, function, dictionary

Thanks for your help - just starting out so imagine there's some serious issues with my logic here.

Trying to write a program, given an input, if a letter from that input is found in a dictionary, replace the letter with the corresponding value.

Really stuck where I'm going wrong. Anyone able to help / suggest an alternative logic that may work?

```
var leetDic = ["A" : "4",
               "B" : "6",
               "E" : "3",
               "I" : "1",
               "L" : "1",
               "M" : "(V)",
               "N" : "(/)",
               "O" : "0",
               "S" : "5",
               "T" : "7",
               "V" : "(/",
               "W" : "`//]"]


func leetConverter(leet: String) {

    var leet1 = leet.uppercased()

    for i in leet1.characters { 

        if i == leetDic.keys { //ERROR "Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type Character and dictionary"

            i = leetDic.values // ERROR "cannot assign value 'i' is a let constant"
        } else {

            return i
        }
    }


}

var test = leetConverter(leet: "Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are comparing character and array also you can assign value to i in loop because it is constant you can go like this way.

```
func leetConverter(leet: String) -> String {
    var leet1 = leet.uppercased()
    var newString = String()
    for ch in leet1.characters {
        let str = String(ch)
        if let value = leetDic[str] {
            newString.append(value)
        } else {
            newString.append(str)
        }
    }
    return newString
}
```

More Swifty way

```
func leetConverter(leet: String) -> String {
    let str = leet.characters.map { leetDic[String($0).uppercased()] ?? String($0) }.joined()
    return str
}
```

Comment: And of course, you can say `leetDic[String($0)] ?? String($0)` in the map transform ;) Although `leetDict` should probably be a `[Character: String]`, in which case `leetDic[$0] ?? String($0)`.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the good suggestion, Edited answer with it.