# Swift: matching separate characters from a string with values in a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary

I want to match separate characters from a users' input to a value in a dictionary. The user types something into a textfield, which then gets converted to a group of words associated with the letters they just typed.
For example, if someone types "Hello", for each letter in the word (five in this case) a match should be made from the dictionary, resulting in five words as output: one for each letter in the word "Hello".

This is my dictionary (for convenience just a small part, it contains all letters from the alphabet):

```
let dict:[String:String] = ["A":"Awesome",
                            "B":"Bravo",
                            "C":"Cool"]
```

From the `inputField` (which is a `UITextField`), I convert the text into an array for the individual characters:

```
let textString = inputField.text
let arrayOfString = Array(textString.characters)
```

I'm guessing I need to iterate through my dictionary using a for-in loop, but i'm not sure how to approach this. Should I be using an array? Or even `.characters` to get the individual letters?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694617/beginner-swift-converting-string-if-letter-in-dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For keeping order as original word letters:

```
let dict:[String:String] = ["A":"Awesome",
                                "B":"Bravo",
                                "C":"Cool"]
let words = "AbCd".uppercased().characters.flatMap { dict[String($0)] }
print(words) // ["Awesome", "Bravo"]
```

Keep in mind that this solution simply skips the missing letter - not sure if that is what you want

Comment: You can merge the map and flatMap together – `let words = "AbCd".uppercased().characters.flatMap { dict[String($0)] }`. Although `dict` should probably be a `[Character: String]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easier on yourself by building the dictionary as Character to String from an array of Strings if you assume the first letter of the word should be the key:

```
import Foundation

let words = [
    "Awesome",
    "Bravo",
    "Cool"]

let dict = words.reduce([Character:String]()) { dict, word in
    guard let c = word.lowercased().characters.first else { return dict }
    var mutDict = dict
    mutDict[c] = word
    return mutDict
}
```

Then lookup the words by normalising the user input in the same way as the dictionary's key (I'm lowercasing in the example), then flat-map to throw out any non-matches.

```
let wordsMatchingUserInput = userInput.lowercased().characters.map { dict[$0] }.flatMap { $0 }
```

Then join them all up

```
let outputString = wordsMatchingUserInput.joined(separator: " ")
```